# Using python to control a phone with bluetooth

Tags: python, bluetooth

I would like to know if there are any API's for python to programmatically control a phone, like starting and ending calls, but also to record conversations.

I would also like to use the Headphones and Mic of the computer to talk over the phone.

Any info would be great, I tried googling for something, but nothing useful came up.

Comment: you've been a touch vague - is there any more detail you can provide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> PyBluez is an effort to create python wrappers around system Bluetooth resources to allow Python developers to easily and quickly create Bluetooth applications.

Unfortunately I've not found a page dedicated to its features, but it could be a good starting point, whether everything you need is in its feature set, or if you could build your application upon it by extending it.

http://code.google.com/p/pybluez/

Comment: Thanks! I also found this neat guide from nokia:
http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_send_AT_commands_and_Dial_with_Python_and_Bluetooth
It explains alot about making calls using pybluez

Now the next problem will be to use the speakers and mic from the computer to conversate :)

Answer (score 2):

Be careful when using PyBluez! The results will actually depend on the BT-USB dongle you are using. Depending on the hardware(the BT chip in there), PyBluez will use one or another BT stack - for example there was one from WIDCOMM. Results will vary, as PyBluez is actually wrapping around those stacks - all of which are far from complete.

So, when you have a working project, be sure to know what actual BT stack you were using :)

For Python audio stuff, you could try [this](http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/).

Comment: One thing to remember, since the Pybluez library is so underdeveloped, and will not work with most BT Dongle drivers, it is a good idea to never actually install the drivers! **Try to make BT dongles install with standard MS Windows drivers!!! **